# MVC Java script loop async controller data

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, loops, model-view-controller, async-await

I'm running a script and want to output an alert when it is finished loading all data.
The problem is, I have a for loop and call a MVC controller function,
but the alert is outputted/triggered bevor the data is loaded completely.
It seems like the data fetching from the controller runs asynchronously.

I added the async  and await but it changed nothing.

Script:

```
async  function checkform() {
        $("#faRueckmeldungen").html("")
        let _clipboard="";
        var _fanr = $('#FaNr').val();     
        
        var _faArray = _fanr.replace(/\n/g, " ").split(" ");

      for (var i = 0; i <= _faArray.length; i++) {

            var _fA = _faArray[i];

            if (_fA < 2013810000) {
                (document.getElementById("FaNr")).style.backgroundColor = "OrangeRed";
                alert("FaNr #" + _fA + " nicht korrekt!");
            }
            else {

                var url = "/FaInfos/FaRueckmeldung";
                $.get(url, { faNr: _fA }, await function (data) {                  

                    $("#faRueckmeldungen").append(data[0]);
                    _clipboard += data[1];
                     navigator.clipboard.writeText(_clipboard);    
                })
          }
     } 
     alert("finished")
    }
```

Controller function:

```
    public  JsonResult FaRueckmeldung(string faNr)
    {
        if (faNr == null)
            return null;

        //Loading data from SAP
        var faHead = SapInterClient.GetFaHead(faNr.ToString());
        var faPos = SapInterClient.GetFaPos(faNr.ToString());
        //<td>"++"</td>

        string clippoard = "Fertigungsauftrag\tMaterialnummer\tAuftragsmenge\tStart Termin Soll\tStart Termin Ist\tEndtermin Soll\tEndtermin Ist\tPersonal Soll [min]\tPersonal Ist [min]";

        string sret = "<table class=" + (char)34 + "table1" + (char)34 + @"><thead><tr>
        <th>Fertigungsauftrag</th>
        <th>Materialnummer</th>
        <th>Auftragsmenge</th>
        <th>Start Termin Soll</th>
        <th>Start Termin Ist</th>
        <th>Endtermin Soll</th>
        <th>Endtermin Ist</th>
        <th>Personal Soll [h]</th>
        <th>Personal Ist [h]</th>";

        decimal VgPers = 0;
        decimal RuPers = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < faPos.RückgemeldeteLeistungRP.Count(); i++)
        {
            VgPers += faPos.RückgemeldeteLeistungTP[i];//VorgabePersonal
            RuPers += faPos.RückgemeldeteLeistungRP[i];//FeedbackPersonal
        }

        string cellColor = "LightGreen";

        if (VgPers/60 < RuPers)
            cellColor = "Salmon";


        foreach (var item in faPos.Vorgangsnummer)
        {
            clippoard += "\t VG " + item;
            sret += "<th> VG " + item + "</th>";
        }
        clippoard += "\r\n";
        sret += "</tr></thead>";

        sret += "<tr><td>" + faNr + "</td><td>" + faHead.MatNr + "</td><td>" + faHead.GesamteAuftragsmenge + "</td><td>" + faHead.TerminierterStart.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") + "</td><td>" + faHead.IstStartTermin.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") + "</td><td>" + faHead.TerminiertesEnde.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") + "</td><td>" + faHead.IstEndTermin.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") + "</td><td>" + String.Format("{0:0.00}", VgPers / 60) + "</td><td bgcolor=" + (char)34 + cellColor + (char)34 + ">" + String.Format("{0:0.00}", RuPers) + "</td>";
        clippoard += faNr + "\t" + faHead.MatNr + "\t" + faHead.GesamteAuftragsmenge + "\t" + faHead.TerminierterStart.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") + "\t" + faHead.IstStartTermin.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") + "\t" + faHead.TerminiertesEnde.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") + "\t" + faHead.IstEndTermin.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy") + "\t" + String.Format("{0:0.00}", VgPers / 60) + "\t" + String.Format("{0:0.00}", RuPers);

        for (int i = 0; i < faPos.GutmengeGesamt.Count(); i++)
        {
            clippoard += "\t" + faPos.GutmengeGesamt[i];
            sret += "<td>" + faPos.GutmengeGesamt[i] + "</td>";
        }
        clippoard += "\r\n";
        sret += "</tr></table>";

        return  Json(new List<string>{sret,clippoard}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Please help.

Best regards Simon

Comment: I assume this is the line where you make an api call `$.get(url, { faNr: _fA }, await function (data) { `. Am I right ?

Comment: Correct Alex. I also tried to add a **Thread.sleep** into the api call                `$.get(url, { faNr: _fA }, await function (data) {     
                    $("#faRueckmeldungen").append(data[0]);

                    while (data[0].length < 1) { Thread.sleep(1000) }

                    _clipboard += data[1];
                     navigator.clipboard.writeText(_clipboard);    
                })` with no effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `await` before the `$.get(url....)`. The `await` before `function` has no reason to be there. Add async if you make asynchronous calls in there, though I do not see any.

The idea is that you add `await` to the specific instruction that works asynchronously ( and you want to wait for it). In your case, your callback function that you send to `get` is not the async function, rather the `.get()` itself is the guy you're looking for. The callback function you send there is being executed after the api call is done, and it's handled by `.get()` itself.

So your code will look a little something like this:

```
await $.get(
        url,
        { faNr: _fA },
        function (data) {                  
           $("#faRueckmeldungen").append(data[0]);
           _clipboard += data[1];
           navigator.clipboard.writeText(_clipboard);    
        }
      )
```

Comment: Thank you Alex! I thought I tested it with the `await` in front of the `get` request, I guess I got 'code blindness'...